# WordPress: add_filter in plugin being ignored - json media type

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I'm writing plugin that will use json file. Hence I need to be able to upload them in media in wp-admin. However I got the standard error that 'Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.' I have added the following code at the very beginning of my plugin' main file:

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types' );
function my_myme_types( $mime_types=array() ) {
    $mime_types['json'] = 'application/json';
    return $mime_types;
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45633

This is a core bug, for whatever reason the mime type is being interpreted as `text/plain`.

Until the bug is fixed, a hotfix is available as a filter in the comments on that ticket